# URL Case Sensitivity (Unbounce Landing Pages)

Tags: wordpress, unbounce

I'm using the Unbounce landing page plugin to create landing pages on my Wordpress website. Currently, the website treats page ULRs the same if they do or don't contain capitalization. The Unbounce landing page URLs can't contain any capitalization and the website returns 404 errors if they do.

Does anyone know how to configure the Wordpress website to properly handle the different types of Unbounce URLs?

I wonder if something like this would help: https://en-ca.wordpress.org/plugins/uppercase-to-convert-lowercase-in-url/

Thanks!

Comment: If your problem solved ?? I also facing same problem

Comment: I have not resolved this yet. I'm considering editing my httpd.conf file.

Comment: Do you want to convert uppercase url into lowercase ?

Comment: https://wordpress.org/plugins/case-insensitive-urls/ - Check out this one.